# Некорректность вывода значения

Tags: python

Есть,код который печает цифры,которые не входят в десятичное число по возрастанию.Как сделать,чтоб ответ печатался без запятой

```
print(*sorted(set(input('число: ')) ^ set(map(str,range(10)))))
```

Comment: Запустил Ваш код, запятых в выводе не обнаружил. Как выглядит вывод у Вас? (Запускал в PyCharm - python3.7)

Comment: число вводится десятичное.Например:2,323

Comment: При каком значении входящего? Просто у меня вывод выглядит вот так: число: 127  Вывод
0 3 4 5 6 8 9

Comment: число:3,321---- , 0 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: запятая при выводе не нужна,не знаю как убрать

Comment: Сделать ввод отдельной инструкцией, и применить `replace(',','')`. Или, как гипотетический вариант)), можно отнять еще одно множество `set(',')`

Comment: Если вопрос резрешился, нажмите на галочку под оценкой вопроса, чтобы его закрыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так получилось.

```
print(*sorted(set(input('число: ').replace(',', '')) ^ set(map(str, range(10)))))
```

Но, как я понимаю знак разделителя зависит от локали (у меня вот точка к примеру), посему, если для себя то пойдет и так, если в программу, то нужно искать как сюда впаять зависимый элемент. Я не умею пока (

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Любой символ кроме чисел — лишний. Перед печатью отфильтровать список filter(lambda c:c.isdigit(), sorted(...))

Comment: Если это впихуется в одну строчку, буду благодарен (без сарказма) если покажете как. Знания лишними не бывают.

Comment: @Fisherman Что непонятного? Подставляйте вашу инструкцию sorted(...) вторым параметром фильтра. И он уберет из нее всё, что не цифра.